# Intermediate Shell Class

Tags: php, cakephp, inheritance, autoload

I have a CakePHP project with three shell scripts that will be run as cron jobs. The output of these cron jobs will be useful for debugging. We've decided to email this output to the support team. My plan is to create a class `CronShell` that extends `AppShell` then extend `CronShell` for any scripts that will be run as cron jobs. Here's the `CronShell` class:

```
class CronShell extends AppShell {
    private $_messages = array();

    public function out($message=null, $newlines=1, $level=Shell::NORMAL) {
        parent::out($message, $newlines, $level);
        $this->_messages[] = $message;
    }   

    public function __destruct() {
        App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
        $email = new CakeEmail('default');
        $email->to(Configure::read('support.addresses'));
        $email->subject(get_class($this).' output');
        $email->send(implode("\n", $this->_messages));
    }
}
```

I have a simple test implementation that inherits from `CronShell`:

```
class TestShell extends CronShell {

    public function startup() {
        // Omit the startup message.
        return;
    }   

    public function main() {
        $this->out('test');
        $this->out('out');
        $this->out('the');
        $this->out('class');
    }
}
```

But the output is:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'CronShell' not found in...
```

How do I make `TestShell` aware of `CronShell`?

Comment: its just a namespace problem i guess

Comment: I haven't seen people include a shell script before, so I'm not 100% sure how to do it, but I'd try `App::uses('CronShell', 'Console/Command');`

Comment: Thanks @Kai, @AbdouTahiri I didn't realize that the second param of `App::uses` was a directory. Reading the docs helped... http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Abdou Tahiri and Kai for explaining what was missing. I just needed an `App::uses` call in the scripts that inherit from `CronShell`. Here's the working `TestShell`:

```
App::uses('CronShell', 'Console/Command');

class TestShell extends CronShell {

    public function startup() {
        // Omit the startup message.
        return;
    }

    public function main() {
        $this->out('test');
        $this->out('out');
        $this->out('the');
        $this->out('class');
    }

}
```

Comment: +1. Note that using a trait is another similar alternative, or putting the functionality in a task. You can only use inheritance like that once, whereas you can use as many tasks (or traits) as you want.